# How to retrieve Json parameters without create any List

Tags: json

{"response":{"id":"4234242424424244","phone":"","details":"OPT_IN","status":"success"},"data":{"response_messages":[{"id":"312","phone":"91XXXXXXXXXXX","details":"You are already opted In.","status":"error"}]}}

Comment: share you expected result

Comment: If you consider `json_variable` your json, you can access its parameters through `json_variable["response"]["phone"]` or `json_variable["data"]["response_messages"][0]["details"]`

Comment: Can fetch its from server side without using or create list?

Comment: Yes sure, you can also always parse it to a variable and access its parameters. If you want a more elaborate answer specify which server-side language you are using and your client-side `POST` request.